# How to get * as String in Shell Script

Tags: bash

I am trying to construct a MS-SQL query but when i tried to put * and print, it will print all files in the current dir (like ls).

here is how i do it.

```
#!/bin/bash 

sql_command="SELECT * FROM test-db.test-schema.test-table"
echo $sql_command
```

and output comes like

```
SELECT file1 file2 file3 file4(all files in the directory) FROM test-db.test-schema.test-table
```

output that is required:

```
SELECT * FROM test-db.test-schema.test-table
```

How can I solve this issue?

FYI: Also tried `asterisk="*"` and `asterisk='*'`  and then `SELECT $asterisk from test-db.test-schema.test-table`, but no luck.

Comment: `*` is the shell wildcard character, so if you want to use it you'll need to ensure you quote it properly: `echo "$sql_command"`.

Comment: In bash, parameter expansion is done before wildcard expansion. Aside from doing the quoting, as proposed by larsks, you could also do your scripting in zsh, where your code would work unmodified.

Comment: Since you are using file names as SQL identifiers it is critically important to first turn the shell string into an SQL string by doubling single-quotes, and then escape the resultant SQL string into an SQL identifier using the `sys.quote_identifier()` (require access to the `sys` schema privilege).
`selectIdentifiers=(); for f in ./*; do if [ -f "$f" ]; then sqlString="'${f//\'/\'\'})'"; sqlIdentifier=$(mysql -Bse "SELECT sys.quote_identifier($sqlString);"); selectIdentifiers+=("$sqlIdentifier"); fi; done; sql_command="SELECT ${selectIdentifiers[*]} FROM test-db.test-schema.test-table";`